# Pipe processing to extract tar buffer in Node.js Child Processes

Tags: node.js, pipe, child-process

I would like to do this by Node.js:

```
git archive remote=git@example.com:repo.git HEAD | tar -x - -C /path/to/extracted/
```

So, I wrote codes something like this:

```
git = spawn 'git', ['archive', "--remote=git@example.com:repo.git", 'HEAD']
tar = spawn 'tar', ['-x', '-', '-C /path/to/extracted']

git.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
  console.log "git error: #{data}"

git.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
  tar.stdin.write data

tar.stderr.on 'data', (data) ->
  console.log "tar error: #{data}"

git.on 'exit', (code) ->
  console.log "git process done with code #{code}"

tar.on 'exit', (code) ->
  console.log "tar process done with code #{code}"
```

However this doesn't work as I expected. What should I change to make this work properly?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Proper command actually doesn't need `-` between `-x` and `-C`

```
git archive remote=git@example.com:repo.git HEAD | tar -x -C /path/to/extracted/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the function exec and not spawn in that case. As seen in the exec documenation it accepts pipes [exec documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

```
exec('git archive remote=git@example.com:repo.git HEAD | tar -x - -C /path/to/extracted/', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    // logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should beware of command injection when using child_process.exec. You can accomplish a similar behavior with spawn by using `.pipe` which you can apply to streams (which is what spawn uses). https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_pipe